# Difference between HP 1810-8G (J9802A) and HP PS1810-8G (J9833A)

Tags: switch, hp

Working in a QA department, I have a HP 1810-8G (J9802A) and I know it suits my requirements, since I'm actively using it.

- it supports a fully configurable mirroring port for network diagnosis (which is the most important point here)
- it supports 10/100/1000 MBit/s and setting a baud rate explicitly (important)
- it can be powered via PoE (less important)
- it has 8 ports (less important)

Now my colleagues shall get similar switches for the reason of monitoring the traffic. Unfortunately, the number of vendors where we can buy is limited and the ones which are allowed by our company can only deliver the HP PS1810-8G (J9833A).

At first sight, it looks very similar:

- can be powered via PoE
- it has 8 ports
- it supports 10/100/1000 MBit/s
- IMC – Intelligent Management Center, which could include the mirroring port
- similar price

Now my question is: is there a major difference between those two that I should know about? Or is the PS1810 simply the successor and I can use it without any issues?

(FYI: I'm new to this site. If someone would have a look at the tags and suggest an edit, maybe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this switch doesn't seem to be a successor. One thing that stands out is:

> 8-port Gigabit layer 2 smart-managed switch purpose built for HP Proliant Servers
>
> The 8-port model has an innovative design that allows it to be stacked on the HPE ProLiant MicroServer Gen8 platform.

This switch seems to be built to connect HP's proliant servers. The throughput is also far less than the standard 1810.

You should perhaps looks at the HP 1820-8G which is the successor I believe. You should still be able to get that one.

Hope this helps you on your quest.

SleepyMan